# DatePicker include Year

Tags: ios, uidatepicker

I have dataPicker in my app implemented. But it only shows month,day,hour. How could I able to add year in the date picker. Any idea?

Comment: Note that you can't get it to show date, including year, plus time, due to width restrictions.   See the [date picker mode reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDatePicker_Class/Reference/UIDatePicker.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIDatePickerMode).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
```

> **UIDatePickerModeDate**
>
> The date picker displays months, days of the month, and years. The exact order of these items depends on the locale setting. An example
>   of this mode is [ November | 15 | 2007 ].
>
> ```
> Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
>
> Declared in UIDatePicker.h.
> ```

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDatePicker_Class/Reference/UIDatePicker.html

Also you can change from storyboard set Mode: **(Refer to screenshot)**

[image]

Comment: That's not a solution if you also need the time.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to add month, date, year **as well as** time, add one picker that implements the dates only using (UIDatePickerModeDate) and an additional one for the time (UIDatePickerModeTime).