# Changing UIDatePicker

Tags: ios, objective-c, uidatepicker

I want to make a datePicker like the one in picture given below:
[image]

By UIDatePicker, as long I searched I think UIDatePicker doesn't provide this view. So, I have designed the above view by UIPickerView but my code is very messy and there are other requirements too with the picker now. Can you suggest some library for it?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13225767/datepicker-include-year

Comment: We are not a good guesser! Specify what functionality and requirement you have.

Comment: Obviously ,none of question provide what you really want to achieve? and if you have a messy code then provide your code in this site http://codereview.stackexchange.com/, so that people can analyse and suggest what wrong in it or a smarter way to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

using a `UIDatePicker` it is possible by changing the `datePickerMode` property:

```
datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime;
```

More on the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDatePicker_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIDatePickerMode)

Also, if you want to change the order, you can set the `locale`property with a locale that has a different date format.

Comment: Setting the mode with UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime won't allow you to change year and month explicitly like the one I have put in my question.

Comment: On the same link that @Jean-Baptiste Yunès posted, there is this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/26515797/906830 which may interest you.